# AngularJS ng-repeat filter has two different params according to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the same filter but in two different places, one is scoped app and defined in the module, one is scoped controller.

Now when using the same filter for the same ng-repeat display it actually outputs two different params.
The filter thats scoped app wide takes all the objects as a param in the filter while the controller scoped filter only takes each item at a time, why is this?

**Example of code**

*Local controller scoped filter*

```
$scope.localFilter = function(item){
    console.log(item); //Single item

    return true;
};

//Called like so:
<div ng-repeat="post in currentStation.posts | filter:$parent.localFilter">
```

*App wide filter*

```
angular.module('customFilters', [])

//Used for filtering items from the data usually in an ng-repeat.
.filter('globalFilter', function() {

  return function(items) 
  {
    console.log(items); //multiple items

  };
});

//Called like so:
<div ng-repeat="post in currentStation.posts | globalFilter">
```

Comment: in appwide, using module.filter(), were you able to log $scope.xxxx? can you make a plnkr?

Comment: i now see what's wrong, see noypi's answer below

Comment: I've changed the question so it's more specific.

Comment: it's the same... my answer still explains it,... i will try to expand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
"post in $parent.currentStation.posts | filter:$parent.filterSearchText">
```

You are using filterSearchText as a predicate function (parameter of the filterFilter)

here...

```
<div ng-repeat="post in $parent.currentStation.posts | filterSearchText">
```

you are using filterSearchText as a custom filter.

http://ngtutorial.com/learn/filter.html

**Update**

The way you write a filter is this...

```
expression | filter_name:argument1:argument2:...
```

and you can even chain it like so...

```
expression | filter_name:argument1:... | filter_name:argument1:... | ...
```

in the first example the filter name is "filter"

in the second example the filter name is "filterSearchText"

... so the first example is using filterSearchText as a parameter of the "filter" Filter. The "globalFilter" is use as a filter.

What you really is asking is why the "filter" Filter is processing the first parameter like so... the answer is AngularJS team design it that way.

Comment: But they both return filters, why would one accept the array as ng-repeat and one only the items.

Comment: the first one is used as a parameter of the "filter" Filter... the second one is use as a custom filter... "when I say custom filter" it is the same as "filter" in the first example but it is defined by the programmer...

Answer (score 1):

Your module `customFilters` with filter name  `currentTimeArray` Is not being used any where in your sample and the filter is not returning any value either which contradicts the spirit of the filter. Additionally it is invoking the `$scope` Which was never injected.

The difference between `| filter : param` and `| customFilter` Is that your first sample is passing a parameter to the angular built-in filter function and your second sample is implementing a whole new (custom) filter.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DxY54/1/) sample:

Please note that the first argument of the filter is the "Data Source" ( the entire list). It is the purpose of the filter is to filter the Data Source.

HTML Sample

```
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="row in friends |myFilter:'J': 'girl' ">{{row.name}}</li>
<ul>
```

Js App and filter creation

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(items, name, gender) {                                     
            console.log("name =>",  name, "gender=> ", gender )
            return items.filter( function(i){ return i.name[0] === name && i.gender === gender } );
        }
    });

function myCtrl($scope)
{    
    $scope.friends = [
      {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
    ];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't explain why globally scoped filter locally scoped one would accept different params from the same line.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns typing on an iPad is slow. I just updated the second part which explains it.